# Adding a newline / (carriage?) return in Excel using PHP

Tags: php, excel, special-characters

I'm exporting something from PHP to Excel using `BIFFWriter`, but I'm struggling to get multiple lines in one Excel cell. I'm converting plain data to Excel, but some rows should contain multiple lines in one of the cells. For example: a list of users and the groups they are connected to. All groups should be there in some sort of 'list' in 1 cell.

I tried entering the newline character (`\n`) and `chr(10)`, but without good results. All groups, in this example, appear on 1 line. *But*, when I click on the cell, the cell magically adds the newlines and the problem seems to be solved.

Is there any character that would 'force' Excel to 'open' the cell right away?

Comment: Did you try a Windows `\r\n`?

Comment: Same result, the cell still appears to contain 1 line, until you click it, then it magically opens with the newlines...

I'm starting to think there's no real solution to this.

Comment: It shouldn't be a windows return, it should be a straight "\n"... but the cell needs to have auto-wrapping enabled otherwise it will still display in a single line

Comment: I'm assuming there's no way to make Excel enable wrapping from my side?

Comment: I have no idea using BIFFWriter, my expertise is in my own code, not older versions of alternative excel libraries

Comment: I'm sure I could port a possible solution to this library.

Comment: Look in the xfwriter code for $atr_alc, should be a boolean bit setting, 1 (true) for wrap enabled, else 0 false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Baker gave the correct solution: setting the 'text wrap' option/attribute to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
"hello" & Chr(10) & "how" & Chr(10) & "are..."

You have to keep text wrap on and then auto adjust height, so that all is visible

Comment: Text wrap appears to be my real problem here, I'm using Mark Baker's solution (see comments).